# Can I extract a proof of bounds from an enumeration expression?

Tags: proof, idris

Consider this trivial program:

```
module Study

g : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
g x y = x - y

f : Nat -> List Nat
f x = map (g x) [1, 2 .. x]
```

It gives an obvious error:

```
  |
4 | g x y = x - y
  |           ^
When checking right hand side of g with expected type
        Nat

When checking argument smaller to function Prelude.Nat.-:
        Can't find a value of type 
                LTE y x
```

— Saying I should offer some proof that this subtraction is safe to perform.

Surely, in the given context, `g` is always invoked safely. This follows from the way enumerations behave. How can I extract a proof of that fact so that I can give it to the invocation of `g`?

I know that I can use `isLTE` to obtain the proof:

```
g : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
g x y = case y `isLTE` x of
             (Yes prf)   => x - y
             (No contra) => ?s_2
```

This is actually the only way I know of, and it seems to me that in a situation such as we have here, where x ≥ y by construction, there should be a way to avoid a superfluous case statement. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `map (\y = x - y) [1, 2 .. x]` there needs to be a proof `\y => LTE y x` for every element of `[1, 2 .. x]`. There is [`Data.List.Quantifiers.All`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/base_doc/docs/Data.List.Quantifiers.html) for this: `All (\y => LTE y x) [1, 2 .. x]`.

But constructing and applying this proof is not so straight-forward. You could either build a proof about the range function `lteRange : (x : Nat) -> All (\y => LTE y x) (natRange x)` or define a function that returns a range and its proof `lteRange : (x : Nat) -> (xs : List Nat ** All (\y => LTE y x) xs)`. For simplicity, I'll show an example with the second type.

```
import Data.List.Quantifiers

(++) : All p xs -> All p ys -> All p (xs ++ ys)
(++) []        ys = ys
(++) (x :: xs) ys = x :: (xs ++ ys)

lteRange : (x : Nat) -> (xs : List Nat ** All (\y => LTE y x) xs)
lteRange Z = ([] ** [])
lteRange (S k) = let (xs ** ps) = lteRange k in
  (xs ++ [S k] ** weakenRange ps ++ [lteRefl])
  where
    weakenRange : All (\y => LTE y x) xs -> All (\y => LTE y (S x)) xs
    weakenRange []       = []
    weakenRange (y :: z) = lteSuccRight y :: weakenRange z
```

Also, `map` only applies one argument, but `(-)` needs the proof, too. So with a little helper function …

```
all_map : (xs : List a) -> All p xs -> (f : (x : a) -> p x -> b) -> List b
all_map [] [] f = []
all_map (x :: xs) (p :: ps) f = f x p :: all_map xs ps f
```

We can roughly do what you wanted without checking for `LTE` during the run-time:

```
f : Nat -> List Nat
f x = let (xs ** prfs) = lteRange x in all_map xs prfs (\y, p => x - y)
```